# Customizing multiple rootlocus plot colors (scale of grey) Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, customization, grayscale

I would like to customize the color of my rootlocus plot.
I use a for cycle to plot 10 rootlocus (with slightly different systems in the loop) and I would like every of them to be of a different shade of grey. I thought to use the gray command to obtain a matrix to store the RGB data and then use this matrix in the rlocus(sys,K,'style') command (choosing the i-th line at the i-th iteration of my cycle). Unfortunately the command requires the style to be a cell (for example 'g' or 'b') and not a vector of numbers.

This is a sample of my code:

```
figure()
hold on
L = [sys1, sys2, ..., sys10];
colors = gray(10);
for i = 0:9
 rlocus (L(i+1), 'Color', colors(i+1, :));
end
```

Comment: I've an idea but it would help if you posted the code you already have. You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and then come back here and edit your question to make it easier for us to answer.

Comment: I've edited the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`rlocus()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/rlocus.html) function is not as powerful as the [`plot()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function and only has limited support for setting colours with [`rlocus(sys, 'b')`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/rlocus.html) as you've noticed. However, we can combine it with the [`plot()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function to make use of its power.

Here I use [`[R, K] = rlocus(sys)`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/rlocus.html) to return the values of the root locus, `R`. Each row of `R` represents a different trajectory. We can plot 1 trajectory of the root locus with [`plot(R(m, :))`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) and utilise the strength of [`plot()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) to change the colour however we wish.

```
L = [sys1, sys2, sys3, sys4, sys5, sys6, sys7, sys8, sys9, sys10];
C = gray(numel(L) + 1); % Extra 1 because the last value will be
                        % white and plotting white on white does
                        % not look well :P

figure;
hold on
for n = 1:numel(L)
    [R, K] = rlocus(L(n));

    for m = 1:numel(R)/length(R)
        plot(R(m, :), 'Color', C(n, :));
    end
end
hold off
```